# Pocketsphinx grammar gives false alarms

Tags: speech-recognition, pocketsphinx

I have downloaded a Pocket sphinx sample from: https://github.com/HelloSpoon/PocketSphinx_Sample.git. Here we have 4 kinds of search, right now i am just trying to use the grammar search using a file. But it was giving false alarms.
Do we need to take care of threshold even if I am using grammar file?

****EDIT****

Generally, we add only one phrase to be searched, can i define a list of phrases which i can search. ( i want to do different action depending on the search)
how do i define the threshold based on different phrases)

Code:

```
recognizer = SpeechRecognizerSetup.defaultSetup()
    .setAcousticModel(new File(modelsDir, "hmm/en-us-semi"))
    .setDictionary(new File(modelsDir, "lm/cmu07a.dic"))
    .setKeywordThreshold(1e-40f)
    .getRecognizer();

recognizer.addListener(this);
recognizer.addKeyphraseSearch("keywordSearch", "oh mighty computer");
recognizer.startListening("keywordSearch);
```

and depending on the keyword entered , i want to perform different actions here.

```
@Override
public void onPartialResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
if (hypothesis == null)
      return;
String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();
if (text.equals(KEYPHRASE)) {
  //  do something and restart listening
     recognizer.cancel();
     doSomething();
     recognizer.startListening("keywordSearch");
    }
}
```

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev  can you please guide me

Comment: For continuous listening you need to use keyword spotting search, not grammar search.

Comment: And the download link is wrong. Pocketsphinx android demo is at http://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-android-demo

Comment: Thanks @NikolayShmyrev. I have around 10 phrases. (depending on the phrase spoken , i will do a required action). Generally we add one key phrase ( as in the EDIT above). Will i be able to define multiple phrases